# Building an expression dynamically from a model with unknown number of parameters for pretty lable

Tags: r, dynamic, label, expression

I'm trying to dynamically create well formatted labels for predicted versus observed plots of models.
The model is generated via lm.

It could have any number of parameters. This example has two:

```
 x <- "y   a   b
1            0 7.031 10158.0
2            0 7.054 10036.0
3            0 7.058  9997.8
5           11 6.951 10220.9
6           11 6.960  9727.7
7           23 6.830 10315.0
8           23 6.808 10338.0
9           23 6.832 10168.0
10          36 6.739 10313.0
11          36 6.736 10227.0
12          36 6.783 10227.0
15          49 6.699  9728.8"


cal <- read.table(text=x,header=TRUE)
mod <- lm(data=cal,y~a+b)
```

I was hoping to be able to paste together the expression

```
buildexp <- function(mod){
  parmslen <- length(names(coef(mod)))
  pst <- paste("italic(y)","==")
  for (i in c(1:parmslen)){
    if (i == 1){
      pst <- paste(pst,as.character(unname(format(coef(mod)[i], digits = 4))),'%.%',names(coef(mod)[i]) ) #, sep = '~'
    }
    if (i!=1){
      pst <- paste(pst,"+",as.character(unname(format(coef(mod)[i], digits = 4))),'%.%',names(coef(mod)[i]) )# , sep = '~'
    }
    
  }
  #print(pst)
  pst <- paste(pst,text(','),"~~italic(adjusted.r)^2","==",as.character(unname(summary(mod)$adj.r.squared)), sep="")
  
  substitute(pst)
}
```

As you can see, the output is not very useful -- it does not apply the italic etc.

```
plot(mod$residuals+mod$fitted.values,predict(mod) )
text(20, 20, parse(text=buildexp(mod)))
```

[image: annotated image -- but the label is not quite right]

I admit I may have a fundamental misapprehension about expressions, and would love to understand this better.

My questions

1. How do I get a "," between "b" and "adjusted"...I'd like it to
   display as "b, adjusted.r".
2. Why is the parse statement (parse(text=buildexp(mod))) necessary?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your question? you need `"=="` instead of `"="`, you should add `sep = '~'` to your `paste`s in the for-loop, and use `text(20, 20, parse(text = buildexp(mod)))`

Comment: Thanks for suggestions rawr...what does the sep='~' do?

Comment: I wonder if you could help me a bit further. It is a mystery to me why the parse statement is required -- but it works. It would be great to understand why "returning the parsed but unevaluated expressions in an expression" is necessary in this context.